# JSON.stringify is sending empty string

Tags: jquery, asp.net, web-services, jquery-validation-engine

I am using jQuery 1.7.2 and jQuery Validation 1.8.1 with asp.net. In jQuery Validation there is one option called remote it need ajax call to web service. My thing is I am checking id is already use or not. I am using JSON.stringify to post the value to the web service but it will send empty string but if I send without JSON.stringify, I can see the value.

My code is as below. So how can we solve this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var validator = $("#form1").validate({
      rules: {
        ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder$txCivilID: {
          required: true,
          rangelength: [12,12],
          digits: true,
          remote: {
            url: "CivilID.aspx/IsAlreadyAvailable",
            type: "post",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            data: JSON.stringify({ civilID: $('#<%=txCivilID.ClientID%>').val() }),
            dataFilter: function (data) {
              var msg = JSON.parse(data);
              if (msg.hasOwnProperty('d'))
                return msg.d;
              else
                return msg;
            }
          }
        },
        ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder$txFirstName: {
          required: true
        },
        ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder$txLastName: {
          required: true
        },
        ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder$txMobile: {
          required: true,
          rangelength: [8,8],
          digits: true
        },
        ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder$dpUserType: {
          required: true
        }
      },
      messages: {
        ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder$txCivilID: {
          required: "Civil for is required!",
          rangelength: "Civil for should be {0} in length!",
          digits: "Civil for should be only numbers!",
          remote: "Civil ID already exists !!!"
        },
        ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder$txFirstName: "First Name is required!",
        ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder$txLastName: "Last Name is required!",
        ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder$txMobile: {
          required: "Mobile number is required!",
          rangelength: "Mobile number should be {0} in length!",
          digits: "Mobile number should be only numbers!"
        },
        ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder$dpUserType: "Select User Type !"
      },
      errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
        $('label[for="' + element.attr("id") + '"]').text(error.text());
      }
    });
  });
```

Render Version of Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    var validator = $("#form1").validate({
      rules: {
        ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder$txCivilID: {
          required: true,
          rangelength: [12,12],
          digits: true,
          remote: {
            url: "CivilID.aspx/IsAlreadyAvailable",
            type: "post",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            data: '{ civilID:' + JSON.stringify($('#ContentPlaceHolder_txCivilID').val()) + '}',
            dataFilter: function (data) {
              var msg = JSON.parse(data);
              if (msg.hasOwnProperty('d'))
                return msg.d;
              else
                return msg;
            }
          }
        },
        ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder$txFirstName: {
          required: true
        },
        ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder$txLastName: {
          required: true
        },
        ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder$txMobile: {
          required: true,
          rangelength: [8,8],
          digits: true
        },
        ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder$dpUserType: {
          required: true
        }
      },
      messages: {
        ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder$txCivilID: {
          required: "Civil for is required!",
          rangelength: "Civil for should be {0} in length!",
          digits: "Civil for should be only numbers!",
          remote: "Civil ID already exists !!!"
        },
        ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder$txFirstName: "First Name is required!",
        ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder$txLastName: "Last Name is required!",
        ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder$txMobile: {
          required: "Mobile number is required!",
          rangelength: "Mobile number should be {0} in length!",
          digits: "Mobile number should be only numbers!"
        },
        ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder$dpUserType: "Select User Type !"
      },
      errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
        $('label[for="' + element.attr("id") + '"]').text(error.text());
      }
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well It was my mistake actually remote should be use as function like below

```
 remote: function(){
 }
```

above solves the issue of JSON.strigify sending blank string

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this line:

```
 data: JSON.stringify({ civilID: $('#<%=txCivilID.ClientID%>').val() }),
```

to this...

```
 data: JSON.stringify('{ civilID:' + $('#<%=txCivilID.ClientID%>').val() + '}'),
```

As that didnt work have you thought about offloading the data bit to a function:

```
function getCivilIdData() {
  var data = {};
  data['civilId'] = $('#<%=txCivilID.ClientID%>').val();
  return data;
}
```

Then change your other line to this:

```
 data: JSON.stringify(getCivilIdData()),
```

Comment: I tried that but in my firebug Post I can see like this ctl00%24ContentPlaceHolder%24txCivilID=123456789012&civilID= where I can see civilID is blank and response is like this {"Message":"Invalid JSON primitive: ctl00.","StackTrace":"   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.DeserializePrimitiveObject()\r\n   at

Comment: Ive updated my answer to try things a different way.

Comment: Any chance you could post the "rendered" version of the javascript from "view source" that might throw some additional light on the matter?

Answer (score 0):

You dont need `JSON.stringify()` method there. Because its already a string. `JSON.stringify()` is to convert a json object to string. Change the code like this

```
data: { civilID: $('#<%=txCivilID.ClientID%>').val() },
```

Comment: I tried that but in my firebug Post I can see like this ctl00%24ContentPlaceHolder%24txCivilID=123456789012&civilID= where I can see civilID is blank and response is like this {"Message":"Invalid JSON primitive: ctl00.","StackTrace":"   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.DeserializePrimitiveObject()\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.DeserializeInternal(Int32 depth)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.BasicDeserialize(String input, Int32 depthLimit, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)\r\n   at

Comment: I added render version of the code in original post

Comment: Ok I change my it to  data: "{'civilID':'" + $('#<%=txCivilID.ClientID%>').val() + "'}",   Now my ajax call is not giving error but still it is sending blank string

Comment: Its look like it is having issue with master page. I will remove it and see later on